# Specman e - Temporal expression

Tags: verification, specman

I am new to Specman, and try to use Temporal expression for event which have to trigger every 16 cycle of specific clock.

Can I do the following

`event f_clk is 6*clk`?

If not , how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a * 16 will lead to having clk_16 emitted every cycle, starting from the 16th cycle. to avoid this behavior, you can write this:

```
event clk_16 is {[16] * not @clk_16} @clk;
```

Comment: So I need also to define the f_clk like this? `event f_clk is 6*clk ;                     event clk_16 is {[16] * not @_fclk} @clk;'

Comment: @Rodion Melnikov - should I define any event before or just the code above?

Comment: @Sarti you only need clk - sampling event. The temporal expression "{[16] * not @clk_16}" succeeds on 16th cycle without clk_16 itself, this is the reason why it's emitted, and after that "counter" resets.

Please note that in real verification environments Specman usually looks at HDL clocks in kind of reactive mode and doesn't produce its own.

Comment: just the 'event clk_16 is {[16] * not @_fclk} @clk;'          no need for the "6 * clk"